# Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 kernel 3.5 and fglrx

Tags: 12.04, kernel, 64-bit, fglrx

Does anyone know how to install fglrx with the 3.5.x kernel?

I can live with gallium, an I don't mind dual booting, but I would really love to see better 3D acceleration!

Comment: HAve you re run the installer? has it thrown and error? if yes wait for a new release.

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx

Answer (score 1):

Good news i finally manage to install then with no errors i just download the quantal prebuild packages from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/2:8.960-0ubuntu2/+build/3585042) and everything worked ok no patching needed!

Comment: btw you will have to change the "fglrx"entry to "ati" in xorg.conf and the graphics are not as good as the gallium

Comment: I think what you've done there is to disable fglrx and instead enable the open-source driver (which has no problem running under kernel 3.5). Same effect as deleting xorg.conf completely.